# Как отображать кодировку CP1251 в Bitbucket

Tags: git, кодировка, bitbucket, cp1251

Есть проект в кодировке win1251, Битбакет скрипты в самом проекте отображает как нужно, но если создавать PR (или просто выбрать какой-либо коммит и посмотреть оттуда на скрипты), то ревьювить невозможно, так как кодировка UTF-8. Можно ли это как-то настроить?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент нельзя, хотя тикет у них висит уже много лет.